# Cordova Calendar plugin no funciona en IOS 10 Ionic

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic, cordova, plugin

El plugin lo instalé como lo menciona en su pagina web, pero por alguna razón este no está mostrando la información en el emulador ni en un dispositivo.

Cuando lo corro con localhost si me muestra bien el calendario dentro de la aplicación, pero en un dispositivo no lo muestra.

Como no me arroja nada de errores en el log no puedo saber que puede estar fallando.

Comment: Lo añadiste como dice el plugin? con la razon para que el usuario ocupe este plugin?

Comment: Es para visualizar las fechas y horas de un evento que tiene muchas actividades

Comment: Cuando realizas el build de la app te genera algun warning?

Answer (score 0):

iOS specifics, segun la pagina oficial del plugin

[Git Cordova Calendar Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin)

- Supported methods: find, create, modify, delete, ..
- All methods work without showing the native calendar. Your app never loses control.
- Tested on iOS 6+.
- On iOS 10+ you need to provide a reason to the user for Calendar access. This plugin adds an empty `NSCalendarsUsageDescription` key to the /platforms/ios/*-Info.plist file which you can override with your custom string. To do so, pass the following variable when installing the plugin:

  `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-calendar --variable CALENDAR_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="This app uses your calendar"`

Comment: Si puse el key que dice ahi que es para IOS 10 pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Si no funciona, puedes ver el log que da cuando funciona en el dispositivo?